# transfer variables from page to page using the URL

Tags: php, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head>
    <title>Jugadores</title> 
</head> 

<body>

    <?php
// Conectando y seleccionado la base de datos  
        $dbconn = pg_connect("host=localhost dbname=tarea3 user=postgres password=12345")
            or die('No se ha podido conectar: ' . pg_last_error());
        $v2 = (int)$_GET['id'];
        echo $v2;
//selecciono campos para mostrarlos(todos)
        $result=pg_query("SELECT * FROM jugador WHERE id_equipo='".$v2."' ");

        echo "<h1 ALIGN=center><FONT COLOR=black face=Futurama Bold Font>Jugadores</font></h1>";
        echo "<table border=1 align=center bgcolor=white>\n";
        echo "<tr><td>ID Jugador</td><td>Nombre</td><td>Fotografia</td><td>Club</td><td>Edad</td><td>Goles</td>\n"; //cabecera de la tabla
        $contador = 0;
        while($row=pg_fetch_row($result, $contador, PGSQL_NUM)){
            echo "<tr>
                    <td>".$row[0]."</td>
                    <td>".$row[1]."</td>
                    <td>".$row[2]."</td>
                    <td>".$row[3]."</td>
                    <td>".$row[4]."</td>
                  </tr> \n"; //muestro cada campo de la BD en su respectiva cabecera de la tabla.
            $contador=$contador+1;
        }

        echo "</table>\n";
// Liberando el conjunto de resultados
        echo 
            "<h1 ALIGN=center>
                <form method = 'post' action= 'agregarjugador.php/?id=",$v2,"'>
                    <input type='submit' value='Agregar Jugador'>
                </form></br>
            </h1>"; 

        pg_free_result($result);

// Cerrando la conexión
        pg_close($dbconn);
    ?> 

</body>   
</html>
```

We are creating a table in HTML throgh a while in PHP. We are showing all the values from the table jugador(player) where the foreign key id_equipo(team_id) = $v2 (GET variable obtained through the page that is before this one). The problem here, is that when we try to go to the next page, with :
echo 
                "
                    
                        
                    
                ";

This takes us to the same page with the same table, when this form should take us to a page where we can add a new jugador(player).

Here are some pictures and the code from what happen when I click on 'Agregar Jugador'.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUs9T.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCWKO.png

agregarjugador.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Agregar Jugador</title>
</head>
        <h1>Agregar Jugador</h1>
<body>
    <?php
        $id_1 = $_GET['id'];
        echo
        "<form method ='post' action='checkaddjugador.php/?id=",$id_1,"'>
            <pre>
                Nombre: <input type='text' name='Nombre'>
                Fotografia: <input type='text' name='Fotografia'>
                Club: <input type='text' name='Club'>
                Edad: <input type='text' name='Edad'>
            </pre>
            <br><input type='submit' value='Ingresar'></br>
        </form>
        <a href = 'Jugadores.php'><input type='submit' value='Salir'></a>";
    ?>
</body>  
</html>
```

Comment: Your link is appending "agregarjugador.php" to your current page. In the second picture, you will see what I'm talking about in your URL. Your request for the second page is never making it through.

Comment: Yesss,thats exactly what is happening, each time i press the button, the page keep stacking urls (example: jugadores.php/agregarjugar/agregarjugar/...../agregarjugador.php/?id=bla

Comment: Check all your links and make sure the relative paths are correct.

Comment: the links are fine. The problem is when i transfer the id's. If i erase that part, this works how it should.